# Convert a string to date format

Tags: c#, string, datetime

I want a string value to convert date (`yyyy-MM-dd`) format.
Below is the code which I tried but it is giving me an exception.

```
string date = "20141021";
DateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact(date ,"yyyy-MM-dd",
                                      CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

As you can see `DateTime` expects my string to follow a `"2014-10-21"` pattern. But I can't modify my string. Is it possible to convert string date: `"20141021"` to a `yyyy-MM-dd` format?

Comment: `"yyyy-MM-dd"` specifies the format. Just tell the parser that you're passing a `yyyyMMdd` formatted date.

Answer (score 4):

What about changing the date format to the actual format your string is? `ParseExact` demands an *exact* representation of the format you enter.

So the solution is to change `yyyy-MM-dd` to `yyyyMMdd`.

```
string date = "20141021";
DateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "yyyyMMdd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Care to give some more detailed explanation?

Comment: @Shqiptar_Programmer: Such as? The documentation of `ParseExact` and the method name make quite clear about the need to be exact and I think my answer sufficiently explains that.

Answer (score 2):

You need to parse string to date as:

```
DateTime dt=DateTime.ParseExact("24/01/2013", "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you try to format your datetime, the program will look for "-" symbols in the string you made.

You can either fix this problem by using the "-" symbol in your string (which is the best solution in my opinion).
It will look like this:

```
 string date = "2014-10-21";
```

Or you can just remove the "-" symbols at the

```
DateTime.ParseExact(date ,"yyyy-MM-dd"
```

part.

So it will look like this

```
string date = "20141021";
            DateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact(date ,"yyyyMMdd",
                                       System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code ....

```
string date = "20141021";
    DateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "yyyyMMdd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    string finaldate = myDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it is too late but since <strike>OP</strike> a user wants some explanations..

> I want a string value to convert date (yyyy-MM-dd) format. Below is
>   the code which I tried but it is giving me an exception.

Yes because from [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.DateTime.ParseExact.aspx)

> Converts the specified string representation of a date and time to its
>   DateTime equivalent. **The format of the string representation must
>   match a specified format exactly or an exception is thrown**.

In your case, they are not. `20141021` is different from `yyyy-MM-dd` format. It needs to be `yyyyMMdd` format which exactly matches with your string.

> As you can see DateTime expects my string to follow a "2014-10-21"
>   pattern. But I can't modify my string

But you can always modify your format to `yyyyMMdd`

```
string date = "20141021";
DateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact(date,"yyyyMMdd",
                                      CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

> Is it possible to convert string date: "20141021" to a yyyy-MM-dd
>   format?

There is no such a *string date*. There is a `string` and there is a `DateTime`. `20141021` is a `string` and `yyyy-MM-dd` is a *string format* which you want to parse your string with it to `DateTime`.

A `DateTime` does not have *any* implicit format. It has just date and time value. `String` representations of a `DateTime` can have formats.

Comment: +1 It's never too late. And the clarification was not requested by OP, but by another answerer. OP is missing.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Upss. I thought OP was the asking for a clarification `:)` Fixed.

Comment: No problem. He posted that immediately after posting his answer, so I think he just wanted to promote his own.

Answer (score 0):

If it's absolutely required to have `20141021` be formatted to `2014-10-21` you can do the following:

```
string date = "20141021";
string year = date.Substring(0, 4);
string month = date.Substring(4, 2);
string day = date.Substring(6, 2);

string formatted = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;

DateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact(formatted,"yyyy-MM-dd",
                               System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Otherwise, the answers provided above will give you what you're looking for.